# Не вижу в диспетчере EventSubscriber

Tags: php, symfony2

Делаю по мануалу http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

```
class LifecycleSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->upload($args);
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->upload($args);
    }


    public function upload(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof Upload) {
            $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        }
    }

    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        if ($this->needsFlush) {
            $this->needsFlush = false;
            $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

     public function getSubscribedEvents()
     {
         return array(
             'postPersist',
             'postUpdate',
         );
     }

}
```

Service:

```
services:

    cyber.upload.lifecycle.subscriber:
        class: Cyber\UploadBundle\Event\LifecycleSubscriber
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist, connection: default }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postUpdate, connection: default }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist, connection: default }
```

**В debug:event-dispatcher listener-а нет**

Возможно я не правильно пытаюсь использовать и там ничего не должно быть

Answer (score 1):

Ваш `subscriber` не появится в этом списке, потому что команда `debug:event-dispatcher` возвращает `listener`/`subscriber`'ов которые зарегестрированы в Symfony EventDispatcher, а ваш `subscriber` зарегистрирован в Doctrine EventDispatcher.

Посмотрите листинг команд `doctrine:*`, может быть там будет альтернатива команде `debug:event_dispatcher` только для `doctrine`